# Antonym of "owned by a single party"

Tags: phrase-request, legalese, antonyms

I would like to distinguish between a land-plot that is owned by a single person, and a land-plot that is owned by several unrelated people as a shared property.

I thought of using the phrase "privately-held", but, this phrase does not mean a property held by a single person (it means the opposite of "publicly-held", which has another meaning).

So, what phrases should I use to express these two opposite meanings?

I need to use these phrases in the following sentence:

"We extend the solution from **_** land-plots [owned by a single-person] to **__** land-plots [owned by several people]".

Comment: I'm not convinced that *privately-held* only applies to a single person or family.

Comment: I agree with Jim. Anyway, it sounds as if you want something similar to a community-held property.

Comment: OK, I probably misused the term "privately-held". I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I deleted my answer since it didn't make sense with the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific use,

> "We extend the solution from __ land-plots [owned by a single-person] to __ land-plots [owned by several people]".

I believe that you can use the terms **solely-held** and **jointly-held** to contrast the sense of being owned by a single person against the sense being owned by several people.